# Restriction on power outlet under stovetop?

Tags: electrical, kitchens

I have an island countertop with a gas stove installed on top.  The builders only put one general-use power outlet in the entire island.  I'd like to add more but there are limitations in position due to drawers.  The area directly in front of and below the stove top has space available.  Can a power outlet be installed here?  Are there any applicable code issues here?  I am in Chicago, Illinois

My thought is perhaps it is more likely for spills to happen on the stove area (vs anywhere else on the counter) and it spilling on to cables.  Cables also sort of block access to the stove a little but I dont think anyone typically would stand that close.  Although I would install the outlet as far to the side as possible, there is a higher chance of a cable getting close to a burner.

This isnt my kitchen but it's a similar setup.  blue box indicates the proposed outlet position.
[image]

Comment: pictures would help us to understand your situation.

Comment: OP updated with picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing I would check the installation instructions for the cooktop, it likely has clearance, the instructions are part of the testing lab (UL,CSA,ETL) *Listing*.

Second thing is cabinet makers don't seem to care much with worrying about how you will comply with the NEC. Your problem now is it doesn't look like it is within 24" of end of counter, which if you had then that new location wouldn't be necessary.

> **NEC 210.52(B)(2)** Island and Peninsular Countertops and Work Surfaces. Receptacles outlets shall be installed in accordance with
> 210.52(C)(2)(a) and (C)(2)(b).
>
> (a) At least one receptacle outlet shall be provided for the first
> 0.84 m² (9 ft²), or fraction thereof, of the countertop or work surface. A receptacle outlet shall be provided for every additional
> 1.7 m² (18 ft²), or fraction thereof, of the countertop or work surface.
>
> (b) At least one receptacle outlet shall be located within 600 mm (2
> ft) of the outer end of a peninsular countertop or work surface.
> Additional required receptacle outlets shall be permitted to be
> located as determined by the installer, designer, or building owner.
> The location of the receptacle outlets shall be in accordance with
> 210.52(C)(3)

NEC 210.52(C)(1),(2), and (3) deals with location above counter, *Listing* requirement for on work surface, and not more than 12" below.

Answer (score 1):

The area in front of and below the cooktop would not be a good area for an outlet. A cord plugged in there could catch fire from the cooktop if not careful.
There is limited space under the cooktop as well.
a better location may be at the corner of the cabinet. There can be enough room for a single gang box behind the drawer or lower into the cabinet. The wire will have to be protected by conduit regardless of location.